# Completely Bounded Derivations

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A$ be a type II_1 von Neumann algebra acting on the Hilbert space $H$ and let us assume that every bounded derivation of $A$ into $\mathbb B(H)$ is completely bounded.

Is it true that every bounded derivation of $A\bar\otimes \mathbb{C}I_{H}$ into $\mathbb{B}(H^{\infty})$ is completely bounded ?

Does the answer change if $A$ is also a factor?

Comment: Update : Finally, I am not concerned about II_1.  I claim that the above question has positive answer for any separably acting von Neumann algebra with cyclic vector.

Comment: I figure your recent preprint shows that this is a (presumably) hard question, right? Nice results, by the way.

Comment: Oh yes, it is the same hard as the similarity problem. Thank you so much. Note that if the above question has positive answer, then we have affirmative solution to the similarity problem.

Comment: Yes, I understood that from your preprint. The chances to get an answer here are probably slim, then. ;) Btw, will you be at YMC*A in Leuven this August?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have some other obligations but I would like to be there and meet all of you.